# wxpython - Binding events in external files

Tags: python, wxpython

I am trying to bind events from a GUI file to use code from another file (effectively a "front end" and a "back end"). I can get the back end and front end working within the same file, but when I try to move them into separate files, I have issues getting the back end to see parts (labels, buttons, etc.) of the front end.

I. E. I need the back end code to change labels and do math and such, and it would need to affect the GUI.

I have provided a simple version of my program. Everything works with the exception of the error I get when I try to make the back end see the parts of the GUI.

### mainfile.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import wx

import label_changer

class foopanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, id=wx.ID_ANY)

        box = wx.BoxSizer()
        btn = wx.Button(self,1,"Press")
        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,label_changer.change_label(self))
        box.Add(btn)

        self.lbl = wx.StaticText(self,1,"Foobar")
        box.Add(self.lbl)

        self.SetSizerAndFit(box)

class main_frame(wx.Frame):
    """Main Frame holding the main panel."""
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer()

        self.p = foopanel(self)

        sizer.Add(self.p,1)

        self.Show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = main_frame(None,-1,)
    app.MainLoop()
```

### label_changer.py

```
def change_label(self):
    self.p.lbl.SetLabel("barfoo")
```

All I want it to do is change the label of the GUI, but use an external file.

I am doing this mostly to keep my code separate and just as a learning experience.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common way to do this is the [MVC Pattern](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_Controller) and pubsub. See this [Example](http://wiki.wxpython.org/ModelViewController).

Comment: I think this will be the way to do it... I am reading up on it now... Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to modify `change_label` to accept an argument that identifies the label to change. For example:

```
def change_label(event, label):
    label.SetLabel("barfoo")
```

Then, use `lambda` to create a callback that passes that argument in:

```
btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, label_changer, 
    lambda event, label=self.p.lbl: label_changer.change_label(event, label))
```

Make sure you define `self.lbl` before you do the binding.

For more on passing arguments to callbacks see [Passing Arguments to Callbacks](http://wiki.wxpython.org/Passing%20Arguments%20to%20Callbacks) on [WxPyWiki](http://wiki.wxpython.org/FrontPage)

Answer (score 0):

This

```
btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,label_changer.change_label(self))
```

needs to be

```
btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,label_changer.change_label)
```

and this

```
def change_label(self):
    self.p.lbl.SetLabel("barfoo")
```

needs to be

```
def change_label(event):
    panel = event.GetEventObject().GetParent()
    panel.lbl.SetLabel("barfoo")
```

To clarify, you need to pass a reference to a function to `Bind` that is to be called when the event occurs. wx will always pass one argument to these functions - the event. The `self` that you usually see in the callbacks is a byproduct of them being bound methods. Every bound method (to oversimplify, a function defined in a class) gets implicitly passed a first argument when called that is a reference to a class instance. So since you can't get to this instance the traditional way in an "external" function you have to get to it through the event object.

One more thing, you are not realy separating the gui from the logic this way. This is because the logic (label_changer in this case) needs to know about the gui and to manipulate it directly. There are ways to achieve much stronger separation (st2053 hinted at one of them) but for a relatively small program you don't need to bother if you don't want to right now, simply splitting the code in multiple files and focusing on getting the thing done is fine. You can worry about architecture later.

Comment: While this will work, it's not a particularly good solution IMO. This requires that `change_label` knows something about the other module -- specifically, that the label is named "lbl" and it's in the parent object of the event object. If the main file is modified it may require a change to the label_changer.py file too which raises your maintenance cost.